# Append value to object on certain condition?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a value only if a condition is met (distance != "off").

This is what I tried but I cannot get it to work?

```
var params = {
    q: pizza,
    result_type: "mixed",
    include_entities: "true",
    if(distance != "off") {
        geocode: geolocation,
        }
    rpp: 15,
    page: 1
};
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tou have two options with different implications.

Option 1:

```
var params = {
    q: pizza,
    result_type: "mixed",
    include_entities: "true",
    geocode: (distance != "off") ? geolocation:null,
    rpp: 15,
    page: 1
};
```

or Option 2:

```
var params = {
    q: pizza,
    result_type: "mixed",
    include_entities: "true",
    rpp: 15,
    page: 1
};

if(distance != "off") {
    params.geocode: geolocation;
}
```

Option 1 would mean geocode is defined and you'd need to check for null or whatever you decide the default value should be. Option 2 would mean that geocode is undefined, which is what you suggest you would like to do with your original code example.

Comment: There are other ways to, such as an IEFE: `var params = (function() { var obj = {...}; if(...) obj.goecode = ...; return obj;}());`

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = {
    q: pizza,
    result_type: "mixed",
    include_entities: "true",
    rpp: 15,
    page: 1
};

if(distance != "off") {
    params.geocode = geolocation;
}
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what Liso22 was looking for; there is no way to have `geocode` undefined in a shorter way. Why downvote ?